# Game Center authentication crashes my app if user is not logged in already

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, crash, game-center

If user is logged in in Game Center already app runs smoothly, but if the user is not logged in already app crashes on start. 
-Expected behavior is that user is prompted to login into game center if not logged in already

This is the error message: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is .'
First throw call stack:
(0x30496ecb 0x3ac31ce7 0x32db01db 0x3049a414 0x303e4967 0x32f8e71b 0x310b906d 0x3049a414 0x303e4967 0x3b11ad53 0x3b11ad3f 0x3b11d6c3 0x30461641 0x3045ff0d 0x303ca729 0x303ca50b 0x353396d3 0x32d2b871 0x10d05d 0x3b12fab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

This is the code to authenticate user:

```
 - (void)authenticateLocalUser {
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        NSLog(@"...");
    } else {
        // ios 6.0 and above
        [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && viewcontroller) {
                [viewcontroller presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

            }
            else {
                [self checkLocalPlayer];
            }
        })];
    }
}
```

**EDIT- More Details.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDUsta lead me to right answer. the key was to use: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController`

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;



    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        NSLog(@"There is no system version less than 6.0, just upgrade you guys.");
    } else {
        // ios 6.0 and above

        [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* ViewController, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && ViewController) {
                [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                 NSLog(@"aAAAAAAAAAA");            }
            else {
                [self checkLocalPlayer];
            }
        })];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from the error message : "Application tried to present modal view controller on itself." You're trying to present "viewcontroller" on "viewcontroller".

```
[viewcontroller presentViewController:viewController...];
```

I believe this code belongs to a UIViewController class, so;

```
[self presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't compile. It shows the red error msg: No visible @interface for GameCenterFiles declares the selector' presentViewController:animated:completion:'

Comment: You should send the presentViewController: message to your current view controller.

For example, if you're using navigation controller;

UIViewController* currentViewController = self.navigationController.visibleViewController;
[currentViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: thanks, your hint was helpful. I used [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];